# Conditional Panel and Radio Button Selection not working

Tags: shiny

I am trying to use conditional panel based on the input on a Radio button, which is as below

```
radioButtons("Type","Review Type:",c("Type1","Type2","Type3"),inline=T)
```

conditional panel statements are as below,

```
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.Type == 'Type1'",wellPanel(
radioButtons("Question1", "do you know R shiny?"choices = c("Y","N","NA"),selected = "Y",inline=T)

conditionalPanel(condition = "input.Type == 'Type2'",wellPanel(
radioButtons("Question1", "do you know Python?"choices = c("Y","N","NA"),selected = "Y",inline=T)


conditionalPanel(condition = "input.Type == 'Type3'",wellPanel(
radioButtons("Question1", "do you know Java?"choices = c("Y","N","NA"),selected = "Y",inline=T)
```

if you notice in the conditional panel the radioButton id ("Question1") is same across all the conditional panel, condition as such is working for me, but I have set `selected = "Y"`for all the radiobuttons which for some reason is not working as desired (it only work on the third conditionalpanel)

Answer (score 0):

It's behaving this way because all your `radioButtons` have the same `id`, so they are considered as only one UI element. Give your `radioButtons` a unique name and this will work fine:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons(inputId = "Type", 
               label = "Review Type:",
               choices = c("Type1", "Type2", "Type3"),
               inline = T),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.Type == 'Type1'",
                   wellPanel(
                     radioButtons(inputId = "Question1", 
                                  label = "do you know R shiny?", 
                                  choices = c("Y", "N", "NA"),
                                  selected = "Y",
                                  inline = T)
                   )
  ),  
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.Type == 'Type2'",
                   wellPanel(
                     radioButtons(inputId = "Question1", 
                                  label = "do you know Python?", 
                                  choices = c("Y", "N", "NA"),
                                  selected = "Y",
                                  inline = T)
                   ) 
  ),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.Type == 'Type3'",
                   wellPanel(
                     radioButtons(inputId = "Question1", 
                                  label = "do you know Java?", 
                                  choices = c("Y", "N", "NA"),
                                  selected = "Y",
                                  inline = T)
                   )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you , I am passing this response to the database, hence had kept the same id, is there any way I can make his work without changing the ID, like an <if else> condition

Comment: I don't think you can. Using the same `id` won't allow you to to select more than one response for "Question1", meaning that if you answer to "do you know R shiny?" and to "do you know Python", you will only have one answer selected.